# how to disable in another select box when the other selection box is selected in the same row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do disable in another select box when the other selection box is selected (option value = 3)  in the same row.

There are many rows in a table. In each row, there has three select box in each column. If I selected the select box in first column and the option value of selected box is 3, I want to make disable the second select box in the same row.

I wrote the code as the followings.

my code is not working when the new row added in the table after I click Add Row button. I need some guideline.

javascript :

```
<!-- add new row -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var id = 0;

        // Add button functionality
        $("#addrow").click(function() {
            id++;

            /*var master = $(this).parents("table.fancyTable");*/
            var master = $(this).parents("table.stdform");

            // Get a new row based on the prototype row
            var prot = master.find(".prototype").clone();

            prot.attr("class", "");
            /*prot.find(".id").attr("value", id);*/

            master.find(".fancyTable tbody").append(prot);

            $(".fancyTable tbody tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
            $(".fancyTable tbody tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");
        });

    });
</script>
<!-- change select box -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.processing_code').bind('change', function(){
    var data = $(this).val();
    alert(data);
    if(data == 3){
        $(this).parent('td').siblings().find(".parameter1").attr("disabled", "true");
    }
});
});
</script>
```

css :

```
<style>
 .fancyTable .prototype {
    display:none;
}
.odd{
 background-color: #ddd;
}
.even{
 background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
```

jsp :

```
<input type="button"
    name="btn_JobTempReg_addrow" class="mediumbutton"
    value="Add Row" id="addrow" />    
<div class="container_12 ">
        <div class="grid_job_mod height400">
            <table class="fancyTable" id="sortable-table"
                cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>header one</th>
                        <th>header two</th>
                        <th>header three</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="job-tbody">
                        <tr class="prototype">
                            <td>
                                <s:select list="#{'1':'One','2':'Two','3':'Three' }" value="1" key="processing_code" id="processing_code" cssClass="processing_code"></s:select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <s:select name="parameter1" list="p_result_group" listKey="group_id" listValue="group_name" headerValue="parameter1" style="width: 140px" id="parameter1" cssClass="parameter1"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <s:select name="parameter2" list="p_result_group" listKey="group_id" listValue="group_name" headerValue="parameter2" style="width: 140px" id="parameter2" cssClass="parameter2"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <s:iterator value="p_jobTmpEnt" var="temEnt" status="status">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <s:if test="#temEnt.processing_code == 1">
                                        <s:select list="#{'1':'One','2':'Two','3':'Three' }" value="1" key="processing_code" id="processing_code" cssClass="processing_code"></s:select>
                                    </s:if>
                                    <s:if test="#temEnt.processing_code == 2">
                                        <s:select list="#{'1':'One','2':'Two','3':'Three' }" value="2" key="processing_code" id="processing_code" cssClass="processing_code"></s:select>
                                    </s:if>
                                    <s:if test="#temEnt.processing_code == 3">
                                        <s:select list="#{'1':'One','2':'Two','3':'Three' }" value="3" key="processing_code" id="processing_code" cssClass="processing_code"></s:select>
                                    </s:if>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <s:select name="parameter1" list="p_result_group" listKey="group_id" listValue="group_name" headerValue="parameter1" style="width: 140px" id="parameter1" cssClass="parameter1"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <s:select name="parameter2" list="p_result_group" listKey="group_id" listValue="group_name" headerValue="parameter2" style="width: 140px" id="parameter2" cssClass="parameter2"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </s:iterator>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make a fiddle for this

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.processing_code').bind('change', function(){
    var data = $(this).val();
    if(data == 3){
        $(this).parent('td').siblings()
               .find(".parameter1")
               .attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Shahid. Your comment is fine but attr disabled is not submit the value of input/select field to Action Page. So, I use attr read only for input field instead of disabled. I would like to know how to make read only for select/drop down field. I have no idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.processing_code').change(function() {
   if($(this).val() ==3)
      $(this).next('select').attr("disabled", "true");
   else
      $(this).next('select').attr("disabled", "false");
});
```